# Not Found #404 Yii Framework on linux

Tags: php, yii

In my local machine (Windows) my app made in Yii Framework works right, but on the server(Debian Linux) not works.

It always get the page Not Found (#404) Page not found.

The code is in https://github.com/LucasOlmedo/TCCFatecZL/tree/master/PROJETO_TCC_OFC

Can help me?

Comment: Can you please clarify what your app is supposed to do, what the exact error is, and provide the relevant logs and code snippets in the description. Thank you.

Comment: remember that  windows  file names are case insensitive while linux are case sensitive .. so if you havw name with capitalized  letter and in windows  the file is found also if you use wrong capital reference in linux no..

Comment: scaisEdge, i resolved this by your answer, thanks. The name of files was wrong.